# Show legends at the top of all of subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 1x3 subplots with matplotlib.
I'm trying to show subplot's legend at the top all of subplots. But, I only show the last one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6],"c":[7,8,9]})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
df.plot(ax=axes[0],legend=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
df.plot(ax=axes[1],legend=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
df.plot(ax=axes[2],legend=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image]

How do I show legend at the top of all of subplots?

Comment: Have you tried  replacing `plt.legend` by `axes[i].legend()`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `ax.legend(...)` instead of `plt.legend`.

In general, it's best to avoid mixing the pyplot and axes methods.  In fact, I'd recommend using more-or-less only `plt.subplots()` and `plt.show()` and use axes/figure methods everywhere else.  It makes it much clearer which axes is being plotted on, as well as what operates on the figure vs. the axes.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6],"c":[7,8,9]})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(10, 4))
for ax in axes:
    df.plot(ax=ax,legend=False)
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
              ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

# Make some room at the top for the legend...
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

plt.show()
```

[image]